# change the size of a customized view in program?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a starter in android programming. I am wondering is it possible for me to customize the size of a customized layout in program?

Here is the solution I am trying:
1. I created a customized Layout Class called MyLayout and write the onMeasure and onScale method as

```
MyLayout extends ViewGroup {
  public double childWidth, childHeight;
 @Override  
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {  
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);  
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {  
        //In the current version, we should only have one child view 
        View childView = getChildAt(0);  
        measureChild(childView, (int)(childWidth), (int)(childHeight));  
    }  
}  

@Override  
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {  
    if (getChildCount() > 0) {  
        View childView = getChildAt(0);  
        childView.layout(0, 0, childView.getMeasuredWidth(), childView.getMeasuredHeight());  
    }  
}  
}
```

2. create  the XML file of this layout  activity_mylayout, inside the layout I included a imageview as the child layout

   ```
   <com.example.MyLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"  
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >  

   <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:src="@drawable/android" />

    </com.example.MyLayout>
   ```
3. Write the code for drawing the view and set the size of the child view it contains

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_mylayout);
    MyLayout usl = (MyLayout)findViewById(R.layout.mylayout);
    if(usl == null) System.out.println("SSSS");
    usl.childWidth = 200;
    usl.childHeight = 200;
   ```

Now I am having the problem of having MyLayout as null and throws a null pointer exception.  I am probably doing wrong in many places I guess, but any suggestions on the reason why the MyLayout is null?

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing that immediately pops into my mind is that onMeasure must call setMeasuredDimension(int, int) before it exits or later calls to measure will fail.  Even if the width and height are measured to 0 you need to do that.

The second thing is-  if there's only one child, why does this view exist at all?  All you're doing is adding overhead.  Its probably the wrong design to have this layout at all, rather than just using the child view directly.

The third is that you're probably hitting the usl equals null case causing the null pointer exception, but its impossible to tell without the stack trace and xml being used.

Comment: Hi Gabe, thanks for answering. I am adding this child view because I want to have a view customized to a special size, (e.g. An image view that is 3/4 of the whole page) Is there any way to do that? I am guessing that absolutelayout might be the answer, but I also want to change the scale dynamically(e.g. 3/4 to 1/2) in program...  And I debugged the code, the null pointer is because usl is null...

Comment: Its not needed for that.  Use a linear layout with layout weights (3 on the image view and 1 on the rest of your design) and you'll have it 3/4 of the window.  Even ignoring that, the right answer for how to play with the size of an element isn't generally to create a specialized layout to hold it in-  it would be to derive from ImageView and override onMeasure there.